# how to add multiple navigation controllers

Tags: iphone

hi i am new to  iphone. what i did is creating classes named classone.h,classone.m, classoneviewcontroller.h,classoneviewcontroller.m and creating navigatonviewcontroller in classoneAppDelgate.h , .m . now what i need is along with these classes i have to crete new class named classtwo with viewcontroller, and i have to call new to class from existing class how can i done this pls help me post some code. thank u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suppose you click on a button on classone to call classtwo
then on the click event of that button write

```
-(void)navigateToNextController
{
    classtwo *objclasstwo = [[classtwo alloc] initWithNibName:@"classtwo" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:objclasstwo animated:YES];
    [objclasstwo release];
}
```

Happy Coding...